# i have a problem when i am trying to install the npm

Tags: npm

I have a problem with npm. npm install and this is the error message I have got:

`npm WARN enonent ENOENT: no such file or direcotry, open 'C:\Users\pc5\package.json`

[image: npm install error]

I would be glad if you help me

Comment: Does your directory contain a `package.json` file?

Comment: It contains a package-lock.json file

Comment: If you don't have a `package.json` file, `npm` doesn't know what you want to install. See here how to create it: https://docs.npm.red/creating-a-package-json-file

Comment: The `package-lock.json` is not the same thing as the `package.json`. Look at [this link](https://docs.npmjs.com/files/package-lock.json) if you want to know what it is for.

Answer (score 1):

If there no package.json (as the error message states) then you probably just forgot to run `npm init` as @BvdL pointed already out.

See especially  here: https://docs.npm.red/creating-a-package-json-file#creating-a-new-packagejson-file